# Stuck on an excel audit history tracker

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to put together an audit tracker so I can tell when people have changed a shared file.  I think I'm close but just can't get it over the line!
The VBA should alert to any changes in sheet "Client Data" by inputting user details and the details of changes into sheet "User Log" in three scenarios:

1. when someone overwrites existing data
2. when someone deletes a row
3. when someone adds a row

I've worked out how to do 1 or 2&3, but can't join them together.

It's taken from a couple of different sources which might explain any inconsistencies (plus I'm still learning).

My current code below:

```
Dim PreviousValue

Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal target As Range)
    'reset previous val
    PreviousValue = target.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Static lngRow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("User Log")
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange

    If lngRow = 0 Then
        lngRow = rng1.Row
        Exit Sub
    End If

    i = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'track a row deletion

    If rng1.Row < lngRow Then
        With ws
            .Range("A" & i).Value = Application.UserName
            .Range("B" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
            .Range("E" & i).Value = "Row Removed"
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss")
        End With
        Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    End If

    'track a row addition

    If rng1.Row > lngRow Then
        With ws
            .Range("A" & i).Value = Application.UserName
            .Range("B" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
            .Range("E" & i).Value = "Row Added"
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss")
        End With

        Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Names("RowMarker").RefersToRange
    End If

    'track an overwrite
    If rng1.Row = lngRow Then
        With ws
            .Range("A" & i).Value = Application.UserName
            .Range("B" & i).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
            .Range("C" & i).Value = target.Address
            .Range("D" & i).Value = PreviousValue
            .Range("E" & i).Value = target.Value
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy, hh:mm:ss")
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

This starts to work when I overwrite existing data, but as soon as I add a row, it does record that but then gets stuck and any other changes appear as "row added".  It (now) doesn't to be tracking row deletions at all.
Any help very much appreciated!!

Comment: Why is `lngRow` static? As soon as someone adds 1 row, that's never going to equal `rng1.Row` and it will trigger "Row Added", no?

Comment: Trouble is, without it I can't get the row add to work at all.  Is there any good way of resetting it?

Comment: Just store the row count in a variable on a hidden sheet somewhere, and after every `Change()` event if the number is either lower or higher, then you know a row was added or removed.

Comment: thanks - can you explain why it would need to be in a hidden sheet? I'm not clear on why VBA in a separate sheet supports the intended result. Also if you have time, would you mind starting me off with the code?